# Play Scala Compile Error

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

Soon after updating the **java version (1.8.0_66)**

```
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Am keep getting the following error when creating a new play-scala app through activator !

```
Compiling 7 Scala sources and 1 Java source to  /Users/Triller/Documents/HandsOn/Play/play-app/target/scala-2.11/classes...
application - 
! @6oe8pd26a - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.PlayException: Unexpected exception[The compilation failed without reporting any problem!]
at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$playExceptionPickler$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:165) ~[na:na]
at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileFailureUnpickler$macro$56$2$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:175) ~[na:na]
at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileResultUnpickler$macro$66$2$.unpickle(Serializers.scala:181) ~[na:na]
at scala.pickling.Unpickler$class.unpickleEntry(Pickler.scala:79) ~[na:na]
at play.forkrun.protocol.Serializers$PlayRunsupportReloaderCompileResultUnpickler$macro$66$2$.unpickleEntry(Serializers.scala:181) ~[na:na]
at scala.pickling.functions$.unpickle(functions.scala:11) ~[na:na]
at sbt.serialization.JsonValue$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(SerializedValue.scala:104) ~[na:na]
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at sbt.serialization.JsonValue.parse(SerializedValue.scala:104) ~[na:na]
at sbt.protocol.BuildValue.value(Values.scala:11) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: null
at sbt.compiler.javac.JavaCompilerAdapter.compileWithReporter(JavaCompilerAdapter.scala:35) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.javac.AnalyzingJavaCompiler$$anonfun$compile$1.apply$mcV$sp(AnalyzingJavaCompiler.scala:65) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.javac.AnalyzingJavaCompiler$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(AnalyzingJavaCompiler.scala:65) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.javac.AnalyzingJavaCompiler$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(AnalyzingJavaCompiler.scala:65) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.javac.AnalyzingJavaCompiler.timed(AnalyzingJavaCompiler.scala:93) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.javac.AnalyzingJavaCompiler.compile(AnalyzingJavaCompiler.scala:64) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:61) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:61) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:61) ~[na:na]
at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:75) ~[na:na]
```

And I'm not sure of the cause. I tried reinstalling playframework and yet no luck. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I noticed you are using scala pickling. Did you by any chance generate the unpicklers with a different version of Java?

Comment: Not that am aware of ! Would typesafe / play auto generate these serializers when creating new project ? . Infact I tried creating a new project with default template ('play-scala') and the result is same. Not sure of any misconfigurations.

Answer (score 1):

Check JAVA_HOME or java version. This happens if you are using jre not instead of JDK. Downloading latest java and exporting JAVA_HOME to current java should fix this.